# How do I view WDDM driver errors logged by Dxgkrnl.sys on Windows from a crash dump?

Tags: windows, driver, windbg

I'm hunting down a display driver issue which is causing the system to hang when an Oculus Rift DK2 headset is connected.  I'm finding the following MSDN documentation a little confusing:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568225%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Specifically, it mentions that Dxgkrnl.sys will log graphics driver errors to a log in memory (in Watchdog.sys).

My question is, how do I view these logged errors? Are they sent to the Windows Event Log (the documentation seems to suggest they aren't).